# Substracting time data exceeding 24h in R

Tags: r

My data consists of time points, in hours, starting from the start point of the experiment.
Experiments usually take over a week, so the the amount of hours easily exceeds 24.

To be precise, data is in the following format:
162:43:33.281
hhh:mm:ss.msecs
at the start of the experiment data points could consist of just 1-2 values for the hour insetad of the 3 mentioned here.

When I try to substract 2 times points I get an error stating that the numerical expression has for exemple 162:43 elements, which obviously refers to the colon used in the time annotation.

Any ideas on how to be able to treat time variables that consist of hour values over 24? 
I tried the strptime function, with %H as argument, but that limits me to 24 hours.

Here is some example data:

```
V1           V2 V3        V4                       V5             
75:45:32.487 NA 17       ####revFalsePoke is 112  TRUE
75:45:32.487 NA 17          ####totalwindow is 5  TRUE
75:46:32.713 NA  1          ####Criteria not met  TRUE
75:46:49.846 NA  6      ####revCorrectPoke is 37  TRUE
75:46:52.336 NA  9   ####revDeliberateLick is 34  TRUE
75:46:52.351 NA  9          ####totalwindow is 5  TRUE
75:46:52.598 NA  1          ####Criteria not met  TRUE
75:47:21.332 NA  6      ####revCorrectPoke is 38  TRUE
75:47:23.440 NA  9   ####revDeliberateLick is 35  TRUE
75:47:23.455 NA  9          ####totalwindow is 6  TRUE
75:47:23.657 NA  1      ####rev Criteria not met  TRUE
75:47:44.731 NA 17       ####revFalsePoke is 113  TRUE
75:47:44.731 NA 17          ####totalwindow is 6  TRUE
```

Comment: You've gotta use something like `strsplit` and integer math. I've answered a similar question in the past but cannot find it now.

Comment: The relevant integer math is probably `%%` and `%/%`. Use `help("%%")` for details. I'm not clear on exactly what your question is.

Comment: Matthew: I tried your code, however I get the following error message when I try to run the function on my own data: Error in strsplit(timesteps, ":") : non-character argument . I think it has to do with my data not being in a vector, but in a dataframe. What I tried to do was the following: timesteps <- c(x$V1) in order to get my data, which is in dataframe x; variable v1 into a vector. I unfortunately still get the same error message. Frank: My question is how I should go about to be able to handle my data format such that I can do basic operations with it (- and +)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you're going to have to roll your own converter function for this. I suggest converting the timestamps to `difftime` objects (which represent time duration, rather than location). You can then add them to some starting datetime to arrive at a final datetime for each timestamp. Here's one approach:

```
f <- function(start, timestep) {
    result <- mapply(function(part, units) as.difftime(as.numeric(part), units=units), 
                     unlist(strsplit(timestep, ':')), 
                     c('hours', 'mins', 'secs'),
                     SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
    start + do.call(sum, result)
}

start <- as.POSIXct('2013-1-1')
timesteps <- c('162:43:33.281', '172:34:28.33')
lapply(timesteps, f, start=start)
# [[1]]
# [1] "2013-01-07 18:43:33.280 EST"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "2013-01-08 04:34:28.32 EST"
```

Comment: Matthew, what I tried is the following:> test<-as.vector(x['V1']) ###time data is in dataframe x variable V1
> f <- function(start, timestep) {
+   result <- mapply(function(part, units) as.difftime(as.numeric(part), units=units), 
+                    unlist(strsplit(timestep, ':')), 
+                    c('hours', 'mins', 'secs'),
+                    SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
+   start + do.call(sum, result)
+ }
> start <- as.POSIXct('2013-1-1')
> 
> lapply(test, f, start=start)
$V1
[1] "2114-12-09 08:56:13 PST" ###is what i get as result, this seems like a sum of al time points

Comment: Please supply some sample data in your question.